# How to access a shadowed JavaScript object field on the prototype?

Tags: javascript

Using the following ES2015 (ES6) class definition:

```
class Card {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    val(){
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

(or the equivalent ES5 and earlier code)

However, doing the following method call:

```
new Card(val).val()
```

throws `TypeError: Card.val is not a function`

```
Card.x.call(Card)
```

seems to have the same issue.

Given that the two names should stay the same, how can I properly reference the prototype's `val` method instead of the object's `val` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just trying to get inspiration of how we can effectively avoid such conflict in javascript, assuming that we have to name them in this way.

To avoid confusion, let's call the `val` you have on the prototype "proto `val`" and the one you assign in the constructor "instance `val`".

You can't have a property on the object ("instance `val`") that has the same name as a property on its prototype ("proto `val`") and access both of them directly through the object reference, getting one or the other depending on context. It's just not a feature JavaScript has. This is intrinsic to the way JavaScript property lookup works, and the fact that JavaScript's "methods" are simply properties that refer to functions.

Options below, but let's look more closely at why "instance `val`" overrides "proto `val`":

With either of the corrected versions of the code above, this line:

```
var c = new Card(42);
```

gives us this in memory (some details omitted):

```
      +------------------------------------------+
      |                                          |
      \   +------------+                         |
Card>--+->| (function) |                         |
          +------------+       +-------------+   |
          | prototype  |>---+->|  (object)   |   |
          +------------+   /   +-------------+   |
                           |   | constructor |>--+   +------------+
                           |   | val         |>----->| (function) |
                           |   +-------------+       +------------+ 
                           |
      +---------------+    |
c>--->|   (object)    |    |
      +---------------+    |
      | [[Prototype]] |>---+
      | val: 42       |
      +---------------+
```

The identifier `Card` (effectively a variable) refers to a function. That function's `prototype` property refers to an object that we've put the "proto `val`" method on. The variable `c` refers to an instance which has what the spec calls an "internal slot" called `[[Prototype]]` which refers to its prototype, which it got from `Card.prototype` when we did `new Card`. The prototype has a `val` property pointing to the method, and also a `constructor` property that points to back to the function `Card` points to.

When we ask the JavaScript engine to look up the `val` property on `c`, it finds it on the object `c` refers to, and uses it from there; the "instance `val`" has overridden the "proto `val`". If the "instance `val`" weren't there, the JavaScript engine wouldn't find it on the object `c` points to and would look to the object's prototype (what the object's `[[Prototype]]` internal slot points to), and then it would find the `val` property pointing to the function. But the "instance `val`" is in the way.

You basically have three options:

1. Do what you've said you don't want to do: Give them different names. The data property ("instance `val`") could be `_val` for instance, or the method ("proto `val`") could be `getVal` (as method names should generally be verbs), or both (which would be quite common), etc.
2. Create the `val` method in the constructor and don't have a `val` data property at all:

   ```
   // ES2015 (ES6) and higher
   class Card {
       constructor(val) {
           this.val = function() {
               return val;
           };
       }
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   // ES5 and earlier
   function Card(val) {
       this.val = function() {
           return val;
       };
   }
   ```

   Since the data `val` is no longer a property on the instance at all, there's no conflict with the method `val`.

   This works because the `val` method is now a closure over the context of the call to `Card`, and so it has enduring access to the `val` argument. No prototype methods would have direct access to it, though; they'd have to use `this.val()` to get it.
3. Do what you're doing now and look up the "proto `val`" on the prototype instead of on the instance:

   ```
   var c = new Card(val).val()
   Object.getPrototypeOf(c).val.call(c); // ES5+
   ```

   or *(less reliable)*

   ```
   var c = new Card(val).val()
   Card.prototype.val.call(c);
   ```

   or *(even less reliable)*

   ```
   var c = new Card(val).val()
   c.constructor.prototype.val.call(c);
   ```

   ...which, as you can see, it's quite painful. It works because in those examples I'm not looking up "proto `val`" on `c` (because "instance `val`" is in the way); I'm looking it up directly on the prototype of `c` (definitely, in the first example; *probably* in the second example; *hopefully* in the third).